TYPO3 form definition not found in frontend
TYPO3 v12
In my sitepackage I have defined a CustomFormSetup.yaml. In this configuration file I have defined an allowed extension path:
TYPO3:
  CMS:
    Form:
      persistenceManager:
        allowedExtensionPaths:
          100: 'EXT:my_sitepackage/Resources/Private/Forms/'
        allowSaveToExtensionPaths: false
        allowDeleteFromExtensionPaths: false

The form definitions in this directory are displayed in the form editor and also in the select field of the form plugin. But in the frontend I get an error message:
The file "EXT:my_sitepackage/Resources/Private/Forms/contactform.form.yaml" could not be loaded. Please check your configuration option "persistenceManager.allowedExtensionPaths"

I don't know what is missing here. In former TYPO3 versions this worked always fine. Any idea welcome.

You have to add this typoscript to your sitepackage, for example :
plugin.tx_form {
    settings {
        yamlConfigurations {
            # register your own additional configuration
            # choose a number higher than 30 (below is reserved)
            100 = EXT:my_sitepackage/Configuration/Yaml/CustomFormSetup.yaml
        }
    }
}

Additional note: it is not necessary to set allowSaveToExtensionPaths and allowDeleteFromExtensionPaths to false, as they are already set to false.

This was done ("I have defined a CustomFormSetup.yaml"). Without this, the custom form definitions could not show up in the form editor and in the form plugin configuration.

The custom form definition in the backend is added using this code: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/main/en-us/I/Concepts/Configuration/Index.html#concepts-configuration-yamlregistration-backend-addtyposcriptsetup
On the other hand, for the frontend, you need to add this code  - you must ensure that this is correctly added to the typoscript :
https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/main/en-us/I/Concepts/Configuration/Index.html#concepts-configuration-yamlregistration-frontend

OMG: it was a copy'n'paste mistake! Sorry for disturbing you guys.
